# undefined method `model_name' when calling View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the error:  **undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class** when trying to call the New Posts view below.  I've done a lot of research on this, and it looks like it mostly occurs when the instance variable @posts isn't defined in the Controller.  I've also included "resources :posts" in the routes file.

I have declared this in the controller.  Current_user is the @user of the currently logged in user.  I'm trying to create a new record where user_id is filled in with the current user.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Create Post</h1>

    <%=form_for(@post) do |f|%> 
      <div class="field">
        <%=f.label :title %><br />
        <%=f.text_field :title%>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%=f.label :body %><br />
        <%=f.text_field :body%>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%=f.label :quantity %><br />
        <%=f.text_field :quantity%>
      </div>
      <div class ="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Post"  %>
      </div>
    <%end%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `@post` in new.html.erb, you have to set it in `new` method of controller. Usually it looks like this:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

Comment: I've just updated "def create" method to "def new".  The screen flashes with the "new" route in the Url bar and it's redirected immediately without letting me enter anything in the form.  A new row in the Posts table is created however.

Comment: **Of course!** What did you think? Rename it back to `create` and also add `new` as in my post.

Comment: I recommend this Rails book: http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

Comment: That did the trick.. thanks for the help and the recommendation.  Just curious though, what's the difference between "new" and "create" and why do I need both of them?

Comment: new/create and edit/update go in pairs. Where the first part renders the page for user to fill data into, and the second part uses that data to make modifications in the database. Again, read the book :-)